# TSEnable highlight - true by default

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting, plugin-treesitter

I'm using the plugin `'nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter'`, and I can enable syntax highlighting by using the command:

```
:TSEnable highlight
```

However, once I close n/vim it reverts back to disabled. I'm using a .vim file for my profile but can't seem to find out how to set it.

```
" PLUGINS
call plug#begin()

Plug 'fatih/vim-go'
Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'master', 'do': 'yarn install --frozen-lockfile'} " Code completion++
Plug 'preservim/nerdtree' " File explorer
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline' " Status bar feature
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
Plug 'preservim/tagbar' " Tagbar for code navigation
Plug 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'
Plug 'nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter'
Plug 'mhartington/oceanic-next' " Theme
Plug 'https://github.com/ryanoasis/vim-devicons' " Developer Icons

call plug#end()


" THEME SETTINGS
set t_Co=256
set background=dark
colorscheme OceanicNext
let g:oceanic_next_terminal_bold = 1
let g:oceanic_next_terminal_italic = 1
syntax on
```

Answer (score 0):

What I found I could do was auto-run commands, not sure if that's a bit dirty though.

Inside my init.vim

```
autocmd VimEnter * TSEnable highlight
```

Comment: Try it without the autocommand (that is, just `TSEnable …`). Depending on how your plugin manager loads plugins (or lets Vim load them), the autocommand might be required. But this is not « dirty ». It’s almost the same as `:filetype on` but with a user command.

Comment: Ok cool, just wasn't sure if it was a brute force method or if there was a config item I could set elsewhere. thanks!